# Is the sentence 'How I do is different from how others do' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, linguistics

I mean, 'how' can be an adjective or adverb and is used in a different way, compared to 'what' in a sentence.

For example, in the kitchen, people ask me about my recipes and I could say, 'what[the recipe] I do is different from what others do'. In this case, the verb 'do' doesn't need an object behind cuz 'what' is the object.

Then what if I use 'how' instead of 'what'?

For example, "the way[how] I make the dish is different from the way[how] other people do." In this case, we need the object 'the dish'.

Long story short, can I make this sentence shorter like 'how[the way] I do is different from how[the way] others do', or do I need the object like 'how[the way] I do the dish is different from how[the way] others do?' or is it too short and unacceptable?

what I want to ask about is, without any object, whether the sentence 'how I do is different from how others do' is grammatically correct.

Comment: Try “How I do it is different from how others [may] do it.”  The problem with just “How I do” is that it starts to sound like an answer to the greeting “How do you do?”

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from the other one you asked …